# Period of weeks to string with weeks instead of days only

Tags: kotlin, duration, period, java-time

```
var period = Period.ofWeeks(2)
println("period of two weeks: $period")
```

gives

```
period of two weeks: P14D
```

Unfortunately for my purpose I need `P2W` as output, so directly the weeks instead of weeks converted to days. Is there any elegant way to do this, besides building my `Period` string manually?

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is true. `java.time.Period` does not really conserve the week value but automatically converts it to days - already in the factory method during construction. Reason is that a `Period` only has days and months/years as inner state.

**Possible workarounds or alternatives in the order of increasing complexity and count of features:**

- You write your own class implementing the interface `java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount` with weeks as inner state.
- You use the small library [threeten-extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) which offers the class [Weeks](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Weeks.html). But be aware of the odd style of printing negative durations like `P-2W` instead of `-P2W`. Example:

```
    Weeks w1 = Weeks.of(2);
    Weeks w2 = Weeks.parse("P2W");
    System.out.println(w1.toString()); // P2W
    System.out.println(w2.toString()); // P2W
```

- Or you use my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) which offers the class [net.time4j.Duration](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.html). This class does not implement the interface `TemporalAmount` but offers a conversion method named `toTemporalAmount()`. Various normalization features and formatting (ISO, via patterns and via `net.time4j.PrettyTime`) and parsing (ISO and via patterns) capabilities are offered, too. Example:

```
    Duration<CalendarUnit> d1 = Duration.of(2, CalendarUnit.WEEKS);
    Duration<IsoDateUnit> d2 = Duration.parseWeekBasedPeriod("P2W"); // also for week-based-years
    System.out.println(d1.toString()); // P2W
    System.out.println(PrettyTime.of(Locale.US).print(d2); // 2 weeks
```

As extra, the same library also offers the class `net.time4j.range.Weeks` as simplified week-only duation.

Answer (score 0):

The Period toString method only handles Day, Month and Year.

as you can see below is `toString()` method from `class java.time.Period`.

So Unfortunately I think you need to create it yourself.

```
 /**
     * Outputs this period as a {@code String}, such as {@code P6Y3M1D}.
     * <p>
     * The output will be in the ISO-8601 period format.
     * A zero period will be represented as zero days, 'P0D'.
     *
     * @return a string representation of this period, not null
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this == ZERO) {
            return "P0D";
        } else {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            buf.append('P');
            if (years != 0) {
                buf.append(years).append('Y');
            }
            if (months != 0) {
                buf.append(months).append('M');
            }
            if (days != 0) {
                buf.append(days).append('D');
            }
            return buf.toString();
        }
    }
```